# How to call our design css and js for Magento

Tags: magento

I am new in Magento. I am trying to implement a theme according to our design. But for my new theme css and images not call; I don't understand what the issue here?

I have copied the `modern` folder and after that renamed this folder with our theme name `Brace`

`Location:/app/design/frontend/defaul/Brace`

For css and Js

I have copied the `modern` folder and after that renamed this folder with our theme name `Brace`

`Location:/skin/frontend/defaul/Brace`

After that I have copied my all images in `/skin/frontend/defaul/Brace/images` folder. And then copy my stylesheet in `/skin/frontend/defaul/Brace/css/style.css`.

When I change theme name from admin it not reflect css and images on frontend.

I have searched from net but all solution different that confusing me.

Comment: Is `defaul` a typo or did you really name the directory that way? It should be `default`.

Comment: Turn on [template path hints](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/template-path-hints-tutorial-video/) to see which theme files Magento is actually using.

Comment: I have copied the modern template.and change the name of copied theme(mean modern) as our requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably 'default' instead of 'defaul'?

Are you sure about the design settings of your store? (System -> Configuration -> Design)

In your case the 'Package -> Current Package Name' should be 'default' and the 'Themes -> default' should be 'Brace'.
Also be sure that the configuration scope is set correctly in the sidebar: this should be 'default configuration' or 'the name of your store'.

Sometimes you also need to clear (all) the cache to see results :) (System -> Cache Management).

In the end you could try to use the template hint option as mentioned by Clockworkgeek

Good luck!